# Prove that a subset of linearly dependent matrices is closed and lower dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $1<p<N$ be a positive integer, $S=\mathcal{R}^{N\times N}$ and $$S_1=\{\mathbf{A}\in S:\exists \lambda\neq 0\quad \lambda_1\mathbf{I}+\lambda_2\mathbf{A}+,...,+\lambda_p\mathbf{A}^{p-1}=\mathbf{0}\}$$

I'm trying to prove that $S/S_1$ is dense, but am not really sure where to start.

Comment: What do you mean by *lower dimensional subset*?

Comment: I completely agree with @user296113, your question is not clear at all. You should say at first if $p$ is smaller than $N$. Important: your question refers 1) to the notion of minimal polynomial:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_%28linear_algebra%29 2) to Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Comment: You're right that it should be $p<N$, which is the case in which I am interested. What I'm actually interested in showing is that $S/S_1$ is dense. I'll correct the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, $p$ should be smaller than $N+1$ since the characteristic polynomial always annihilates $A$ and is of degree $\le N$. Thus, $S_1 = \mathbb R^{N\times N}$ (which is surely not "lower dimensional") for $p\ge N+1$.

The closedness is almost immediate. Choose a sequence $(A_n)$ in $S_1$ such that $A_n\to A\in\mathbb R^{N\times N}$ as $n\to\infty$. Then, for any $n$ there are $\lambda_j^{(n)}$, $j=1,\ldots,p$, such that $\sum_{j=1}^p\lambda_j^{(n)}A_n^{j-1} = 0$. We can choose them such that $\|\lambda^{(n)}\|_2 = 1$ for all $n$. Hence, there exists a subsequence $(\lambda^{(n_k)})_k$ which converges to some $\lambda\in\mathbb R^p$. Therefore, $\lambda^{(n_k)}_j\to\lambda_j$ for each $j$ as $k\to\infty$. Now, we can deduce from
$$
\sum_{j=1}^p\lambda_j^{(n_k)}A_{n_k}^{j-1} = 0\quad\text{for each $k$}
$$
that
$$
\sum_{j=1}^p\lambda_jA^{j-1} = 0.
$$
And since $\|\lambda\|_2=1$, we have $A\in S_1$.

As to the "lower dimensionality", I guess you will have to explain what is exactly meant by this.